# Change unbutton title from u inactionsheet button

Tags: ios, uibutton, uiactionsheet

I have a uibutton that displays an uiactionsheet. I want to replace the unbutton title with the uiactionsheet button title. The uiactionsheet button shows a radio band (AM/FM) choice. The uiactionsheet will select the band. I then want the uibutton title to show which mode was selected.
What do I add the the "clickedButtonAtIndex" in the action sheet actions.

```
            - (IBAction)modeButton1:(id)sender
{

UIActionSheet *actionSheet2 = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Mode Select"
                                                          delegate:self
                                                 cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                            destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                 otherButtonTitles:@"FM",@"AM",nil];

 [actionSheet2 showFromRect:[(UIButton *)sender frame] inView:self.view animated:YES];
}

 -(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
   {
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
   {
    NSLog(@"FM mode selected");
   }
   else if (buttonIndex == 1)
   {
     NSLog(@"AM mode selected");
    }
  }
```

Comment: [self.<your button IBOutlet> setTitle:<string based on index> forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Comment: Show some code please.

Comment: I uploaded the code as requested. Hope that gives some insight to my issue/problem. Still working on a solution.

Comment: I solved the problem. I found another problem in my settings. Works fine now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a property for the button and in the clickedButton use `setTitle:ForState:` but firstly check that the button pressed is not the cancel button.